# How do I get a web page to zoom properly in landscape mode with iOS 16?

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone

I am building a site with a simple topbar that needs to fill the entire width of the browser window. What I have now works perfectly on desktop browsers, Android, any iPhone in portrait orientation, and older iPhones in landscape view. On iOS 16 though, in landscape mode it persists in leaving a gap at the edges of the window.

[illustration of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV18e.jpg)

The page structure is real simple, there's a single #page_wrapper_div with everything else nested inside.

```
html {
    all: unset;
    position:relative;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 320px;
}

#page_wrapper_div {
    min-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#topBar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

I found a couple of posts from people who had what sounded like similar problems, which suggested I needed a viewport meta tag:

I have tried several variations of this, with and without an initial-scale=1.0 added in, and none of it makes any difference. It works correctly (i.e. the margins stretch to the edge of the window) in responsive design mode and on my own iPhone, I can only reproduce it on a physical iPhone running iOS 16, or in a hosted instance like BrowserStacks, so it's difficult to troubleshoot. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no Apple device, but `html { all: unset }` might inadvertedly reset some vendor specific property. Or it can simply be you need `* { box-sizing: border-box }` in your CSS. Just thinking aloud...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, neither of them made a difference.